# Symfony Filesystem chmod() sets the incorrect permissions

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-filesystem

I am using the Symfony's Filesystem component, specifically `chmod` function:

```
$this->filesystem->copy($file_path, $target_file, TRUE);
$this->filesystem->chmod($target_file, '0777');
```

But on the terminal the permissions are weird:

```
$ ls -la 1.mp4
-r----x--t 1 user user 3557378 mar 10 07:55 1.mp4
```

It is supposed to look like this:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 3557378 mar 10 07:55 1.mp4
```

Am I doing something wrong? I'm using the 5.2.4 version.

Comment: You are passing a string, and  `chmod()` expects an octal number ( `chmod($targetfile, 0777);`). Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public function chmod($files, int $mode, int $umask = 0000, bool $recursive = false)`

The second param of the function is the number, you are passing a string. And check that you have a correct file owner, usually web servers working with `www-data` user